# Count two or more association records in Rails without counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, left-join

I need to count 2 associations of an User - Comments and Posts. Moreover, I need to count published posts, approved and cancelled comments.

My code:

```rb
    User.where(id: 1) # just for example!
      .select('users.*, COUNT(comments.id) AS comments_count, COUNT(posts.id) AS posts_count, ' +
        'SUM(CASE comments.status WHEN \'approved\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled_comments_count, ' +
        'SUM(CASE comments.status WHEN \'cancelled\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled_comments_count, ' +
        'SUM(CASE posts.published WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS published_posts_count')
      .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (comments.user_id = users.id)')
      .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON (posts.user_id = users.id)')
      .group('users.id')
```

The problem is that the values of `published_posts_count` and `posts_count` is always equal to `comments_count` (User has 8 comments, 1 post, 1 approved post, but `published_posts_count` and `posts_count` returned as 8 (not 1 and 1)).

What am I doing wrong?

SQL:

```sql
SELECT users.*, 
  COUNT(comments.id) AS comments_count,
  COUNT(posts.id) AS posts_count,
  SUM(CASE comments.status WHEN 'cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled_comments_count,
  SUM(CASE comments.status WHEN 'approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS approved_comments_count,
  SUM(CASE posts.published WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS published_posts_count
FROM "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (comments.user_id = users.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON (posts.user_id = users.id)
GROUP BY users.id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the result you expect with this query. I'll try to explain the way it works.

According to JOIN statements, it gets a set of comments(set **C: [c1,c2,...,c8]**) and a set of  posts (set **P: [p1]**) for given user (set **U: [u1]**). As a result you expect to have one set of records (say **R**) out of this 3. Therefore, each record from set C is coupled with each record from set P and resulting records are coupled with records from set U. 
So, if you have 1 user post and 8 user comments R will have 1*(1*8) = 8 records and will look like this:

```
u1|p1|c1
u1|p1|c2
...
u1|p1|c8
```

Finally, COUNT and SUM functions are applied on this 8 records and you have what you have.

**PS**
It's necessary to use 2 different queries (or subqueries)  here: one to count posts and another for comments.

Comment: Thanks! And there is now way how to use joins (not subqueries) for calculations?

Comment: I can’t suggest any SQL-query without subqueries to solve this. But why do you think you need it? Want to do without additional DB queries for performance reasons? Then you could eager load all data records required (e.g. `User.includes(:posts, :comments).where(…)`) and make calculations on them later (e.g. `@user.comments.select {|c| c.status == 'approved'}.count`).